# Cover a single function in nose coverage

Tags: python, code-coverage, nose

Is there a way to cover only some particular functions using `nosetests` coverage in Python? Please note! I don't want to run a single test function, I want the coverage plugin to cover only a particular function. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: You can't only get coverage for a single function, but you can get coverage for a single module. You could then filter out the appropriate function.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want only a single function's measurement? There might be a way to accomplish your larger goal.

Comment: It's worth responding. @NedBatchelder wrote [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.3.1/)